# Using ffmpeg output to HLS and Image Stills

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to combine the output from an RTSP stream into **both** an HLS stream and several image stills. I can do this fine separately (obviously) but i'm having trouble combining things. Can I get a quick hand?

Here are my outputs (that works):

Outputting HLS streams:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i '$RTSP_URL'
    -c:v copy -b:v 64K -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/stream_low \
    -c:v copy -b:v 512K -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/stream_high
```

Outputting image stills:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i '$(RTSP_URL)' -y  \
    -vframes 1 -vf "scale=1920:-1" -q:v 10 out/screenshot_1920x1080.jpeg \
    -vframes 1 -vf "scale=640:-1" -q:v 10 out/screenshot_640x360.jpeg \
    -vframes 1 -vf "scale=384:-1" -q:v 10 out/screenshot_384x216.jpeg \
    -vframes 1 -vf "scale=128:-1" -q:v 10 out/screenshot_128x72.jpeg
```

Any help is appreciated (I also posted a bounty ^_^)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i '$RTSP_URL'
    -c:v copy -b:v 64K -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/stream_low \
    -c:v copy -b:v 512K -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/stream_high \
    -vframes 1 -vf "scale=1920:-1" -q:v 10 out/screenshot_1920x1080.jpeg \
    -vframes 1 -vf "scale=640:-1" -q:v 10 out/screenshot_640x360.jpeg \
    -vframes 1 -vf "scale=384:-1" -q:v 10 out/screenshot_384x216.jpeg \
    -vframes 1 -vf "scale=128:-1" -q:v 10 out/screenshot_128x72.jpeg
```

Note that your "HLS" streams is actually a RTMP stream as the output protocol says. Also, with `-c:v copy`, there's no video encoding, so `-b:v` has no effect.